# Which one will give better quality to do power compaction between slow press and quick hit?

Tags: metallurgy

I would like to do compaction to make small gears. I have seen a lot of videos on Youtube how to do it, mostly by slowly press the metal powder into the mold. But I just have a simple tool, I don't have a proper one. Instead of slowly press the powder into the mold, I would like to hit the powder quickly in the mold. So my question is, *which one will give better quality (strength) to do power compaction between **slow press** and **quick hit**?* We knew that pressure is affected by force and force is affected by mass and velocity/momentum. To both the process will be performed the same treatment, sintering.

Comment: I imagine quick hits could cause damage in addition to being uneven and difficult to control, or unable to apply sufficient sustained pressure.

Comment: @DKNguyen, it is very possible. It was in my mind why I asked this question. But however, I need analysis from them who really understand about metallurgy.

Comment: The search terms you appear to be looking for is "hot pressing vs static pressing" for "compaction" or "sintering". However, I suspect none of these papers actually applies in your case since it sounds like you're planning on a crude method such as banging on it with a hammer.

Comment: Why is earth put back in trenches in layers with each being compressed? Why do some hydraulic presses exceed 1000 tons pressure? and all applied in one cycle but not as a single rapid impact?

Comment: @SolarMike, I don't know why. But I saw in Youtube, to harden many metals, like to make crankshaft, they hammer that hot shaft with a very big hammer rather than to press it slowly. So, still any possibility to use quick hit/hammer rather than using slow press as normally is done, especially because after that compaction they will be sintered to make them more coherent.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I am not really sure. But what I meant is like what just like my comment to SolarMike above.

Comment: For crankshafts, is that to harden it? Or to make the metal "flow" directionally through the bearings and ribs?

Comment: @SolarMike, from what I learned, it is intended for both.

Comment: The webs are not hard - can be filed easily...